# Calling Eigen library to do the linear operation of the matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I am a rookie of coding and I have written a c++ procedure which calls the Eigen library to do the linear operation of the matrix. Please help me to improve the efficiency of the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Weight coefficient matrix
    Eigen::MatrixXd wi_1,wi_2,wi_3,wi_4;
    wi_1.resize(100,2);
    wi_2.resize(100,100);
    wi_3.resize(100,100);
    wi_4.resize(5,100);
    wi_1.setOnes();
    wi_2.setOnes();
    wi_3.setOnes();
    wi_4.setOnes();

    // Bias vector
    Eigen::VectorXd bias_1,bias_2,bias_3,bias_4,Y;
    bias_1.resize(100);
    bias_2.resize(100);
    bias_3.resize(100);
    bias_4.resize(5);
    bias_1.setOnes();
    bias_2.setOnes();
    bias_3.setOnes();
    bias_4.setOnes();
    Eigen::Matrix<double,5,1> y_mean;
    Eigen::Matrix<double,5,1> y_scale;
    Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1> x_mean;
    Eigen::Matrix<double,2,1> x_scale;

    y_mean.setOnes();
    y_scale.setOnes();
    y_mean.setOnes();
    x_scale.setOnes();

    int n = 0;
    int layer;
    clock_t start,finish;
    double totaltime;
    start=clock();
    while (n<10000)
    {
        Y.resize(2);
        layer = 0;
        Y << 0.185, 0.285;//inputx[1], x[0];
        Y = (Y.array() - x_mean.array()) / x_scale.array();

        //ANN forward
        while (layer < 4)
        {
            layer++;
            switch (layer) {
            case 1:{
                Y = wi_1 * Y + bias_1;
                //                                        Info << "ANN forward layer1" << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                Y = wi_2 * Y + bias_2;
                //                                        Info << "ANN forward layer2" << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                Y = wi_3 * Y + bias_3;
                //                                        Info << "ANN forward layer3" << endl;
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                Y = wi_4 * Y + bias_4;
                //                                        Info << "ANN forward layer4" << endl;
                break;
            }
            default:{
                cout<<"error"<<endl;
                break;
            }
            }

            //Relu activation function
            if (layer < 4)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Y.size(); i++)
                {
                    Y(i) = ((Y(i) > 0) ? Y(i) : 0);
                }
            }
        }
        //inverse standardization
        Y = Y.array() * y_scale.array() + y_mean.array();
        n++;
    }
    finish=clock();
    totaltime=(double)(finish-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC*1000;
    cout<<"\n Running time is "<<totaltime<<"ms！"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please tell us more about the task that this code performs. (MathJax is available for mathematical notation.) See [ask].

Comment: Also, the current title is very generic. Unless your code also is very generic, please change your title to be more specific. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.